# Renaming puts in namespace causes issue in TCL

Tags: tcl

When I am trying to rename the puts command inside name-space, It causes the problem. I am renaming puts because I don't want to display the echo statement of particular procedure.

```
namespace eval temp {
    namespace export print_proc
    proc replacement_puts args {}
    proc silentEval {script} {
        rename puts original_puts
        interp alias {} puts {} temp::replacement_puts
        catch [list uplevel 1 $script] msg opts
        rename puts {}
        rename original_puts puts
        return -options $opts $msg
    }
    proc print_proc {} {
        puts "before call"
        silentEval {a}
        puts "aftter call"
    }
    proc a {} {
        puts "inner call"
    }
}

package provide temp 1.0
```

In Example, I don't want to display the echo statement of `proc a`.

But after execution, It shows error that `Invalid Command Name "puts"`

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you calling this code? As far as I can see, it's working when I try running `temp::print_proc` in my 8.6.3 installation…

Comment: @DonalFellows yes the same way i am trying to run the code.. Are you able to use "puts" command after execute "temp::print_proc" in tclsh prompt?

Comment: Hope i am clear. I am also using 8.6 version.. @DonalFellows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847898/renaming-command-into-different-namespace Overhere you said that changing function names across namespace is hard to debug. So it may happen that in my case, puts function is in global namespace and i am changing that in my own created namespace. may be that is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to be explicit that you're altering the global `puts`

```
namespace eval temp {
    proc silentEval {script} {
        rename ::puts ::original_puts
        proc ::puts args {}
        catch [list uplevel 1 $script] msg opts
        rename ::puts {}
        rename ::original_puts ::puts
        return -options $opts $msg
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Glenn Jackman's answer should solve your problem. I'd just like to point out that you don't really need to rename anything. With this definition:

```
namespace eval temp {
    namespace export print_proc
    proc puts args {}
    proc silentEval script {
        catch [list uplevel 1 $script] msg opts
        return -options $opts $msg
    }
    proc print_proc {} {
        ::puts "before call"
        silentEval a
        ::puts "aftter call"
    }
    proc a {} {
        puts "inner call"
    }
}
```

when `a` is invoked and it calls `puts`, it will actually invoke the `::temp::puts` command in preference to the global `puts` -- in effect, the namespace `puts` overrides the global `puts`. In `print_proc` we want the global `puts` to be invoked, so we add `::` before the name.

Of course, all this goes for scripts defined within `::temp`, like in the example.

(There isn't much point in calling `catch` if you're just going to re-throw the exception, but I suppose this is just placeholder code.)

Documentation: [catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm)

Comment: @AxT_8041, you should make this the accepted answer.